# How can I best split this entry into searchable words?

Tags: python, pandas

[image: This is a picture of my dataset this dataset is from Kaggle here the link to it: https://www.kaggle.com/code/gleblevankov/exploring-spotify-data]

This is a picture of my dataset this dataset is from Kaggle here the link to it: https://www.kaggle.com/code/gleblevankov/exploring-spotify-data

The type of the column is object, and I want to split/transform this column into a list with words which could be also searchable.
I do want to split the column after every "," to get the word. I am somehow searching for a function which could create the words in the column into a list of searchable words pro row. So for example if I want to plot the column to see which genre is the most used one to not see genre like "rap,pop,kpop" but more "rap" "pop" "k-pop" instead.

I tried to change the type to list but then it aggregates the whole column into a list.

Is there another possible action on how I could transform this column?

Comment: Please give a more clear example to what you are trying to do

Comment: Some my aim is to find which genres are the most popular and most common in this dataset.

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and take the appropriate [action](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73267794/edit) (it covers program input as well). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try running this command:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.Series([x for item in df.Genere for x in item]).value_counts()
```